# Send specific message if no results available using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to have a specific message sent if no results are available. Right now if my job executes and there is nothing to report the email just show up blank.

SP is below

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Mail_profile',
@recipients = 'myemail@somename.com',
@subject = 'Weekly',
@query = N'EXEC PTW.dbo.SP_Weekly',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_width = 150,
@query_result_header= 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Weekly.txt',
@importance = 'High',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@query_result_separator = ' ';
```

If there are no records available when this is ran, I would like to show `No records available at this time`

I have tried to insert an `ISNULL` before `@query` but this is something I'm stumped on. Any suggestions?

---

Would also like the message always show `No records found for 'Yesterdays date'`

Thinking id have to add `dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)` somewhere in there but where?

Comment: `No records available...` do you want your text file to say this or the body of the email?

Comment: Body of email would be best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @subject1  varchar(max)
declare @body1 varchar(max)
EXEC PTW.dbo.SP_Weekly
if @@rowcount=0
begin
set @subject1='No data or any message that suits you'
set @body1='some message'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Mail_profile',
@recipients = 'myemail@somename.com',
@subject = @subject1,
@importance = 'High',
@body=@body1,
@query_result_separator = ' ';
return
end

else
begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Mail_profile',
@recipients = 'myemail@somename.com',
@subject = 'Weekly,
@query = N'EXEC PTW.dbo.SP_Weekly',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_width = 150,
@query_result_header= 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Weekly.txt',
@importance = 'High',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@query_result_separator = ' ';
end
```

Comment: That's what I was missing...Checking the `@@rowcount` Thanks, this nailed it

Comment: Thanks.The above code may or may not work,but the idea is similar

Comment: Yea it does, just ran it. Cheers

Comment: One last question... What if I wanted the message to always say `No records found for 'yesterdays date'`

Comment: I think changing the subject will work,it is  just a variable..try some thing like `no records found for '+ cast(getdate()-1 as varchar(30))`